# Mount external HD ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mount, external-hdd, data-recovery, data-loss

Although it's an abundantly treated matter, I'm unable to find an answer valid for my needs. I had a 12.04 installation of ubuntu and I decided to install the 12.10.

I copied (using GParted) the partition where my system was to an external hd where there is a windows partition. Then I installed the newest ubuntu version and now I want to take back some files (for example my .emacs) from that partition but when I try to mount it, it is not found as sdb and if I mount it from /dev/usb/hddev0 I don't get any output, only a blinking cursor, no errors, no output. I even tried to mount it as an ntfs disk but the result was the same. It's like the hd cannot be detected.

So how can I access data to that disk? Could I get them from GParted terminal instead of Ubuntu one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this in another post. In a "Terminal", try entering:

sudo mkdir /media/${USER}

If you have other users on the same machine, say, fred, create /media/fred as well

Amazing that such a basic issue was not addressed before 12.10 was released!

Comment: In the end I managed to mount my external drive. I used a gparted live cd, booted from cd and from the gparted terminal (which, basically, is a linux terminal) I run sudo mount /dev/myexthd /media. All was OK and I was able to recover my precious .emacs :-). BTW thanks for your reply!